# Is there a way to override the browser re-send form prompt when reloading a page?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, reload, prompt

I have a page with a table, that displays data in four views. The user can edit a record by opening a popup. When closing the popup, I would like to reload the page to reflect the updated record.

So I'm doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        alert("#blabla#");
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        self.close();
    }
</script>
```

which does what it should, but when the parent page is reloaded, I get a `prompt` asking me if I want to re-send the form (YES).

**Question**:
Is there a way to override this prompt? I'm pretty much stuck with the page design, so I cannot do any AJAX/event behavior etc to trigger the update of the table.

Comment: I take it the main page (the one you're reloading) was itself a response to a form submission? A search or similar?

Comment: Given the number of forms used for payment processing, I hope it's not possible to circumvent this feature.

Comment: @DavidThomas: true. Still curious if possible

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: puh... I'm not sure. Old school, frames... I hate to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the main page (the one you're reloading) was itself a response to a form submission (that would be why you're getting the message).

If like most search result pages it allows you to repeat the search (by submitting a form on the result page), you could submit that form rather than reloading. If not, you could include a hidden form on the page (with the relevant search criteria) for expressly that purpose.

Then your JavaScript changes to:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert("#blabla#");
    window.opener.reloadForm.submit();
    self.close();
}
```

...where `reloadForm` is the `id` of the `form` element that repeats the search.

It might be nicer, though, to dynamically insert the row in the search results *without* reloading the page...

Comment: Cool. I'm actually re-doing the whole page and just have to add stuff to the old version until the new page is done. So I hope this does the "interim"-job